# Create a file in filesystem using java

Tags: java

I am creating an `xml` file using document object which goes something like this.

```
DOMSource ds=new DOMSource(doc);

PrintStream ps=new PrintStream("file.xml");
StreamResult sr=new StreamResult(ps);    
javax.xml.Transformer.transform(ds,sr);
```

The file creation is fine and it is getting created in my local directory.

What I want is this file to be created/uploaded into a file-system (`fs:///myresources/myproject/`) using java.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the path in the file name:

```
      PrintStream ps=new PrintStream("fs:///myresources/myproject/file.xml");
```

Comment: it dint work. I am getting the below error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: fs:\myresources\myproject\file.xml; (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: @NewBee Use the file path as fs:/myresources/myproject/file.xml or fs:\\myresources\\myproject\\file.xml. Please note `'\'` is an escape character.

Comment: actually i put fs:///path only. if i have put \ then the compiler itself will show syntax error.

Comment: @NewBee: The above code is working fine. What is the ` fs`? Also, does this directory `fs:\\myresources\\myproject\\` exist in your file system or are you trying to create the directory as well?